# Moving a table over a background CSS

Tags: css, html-table

I have tried to position #box1 under #table1    I try to move it however it doesn't move.  What am I doing wrong. 
 I am new to css.

Edit: I put in my html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en">
         <head>
    <title>Assignment 1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    html{
        background: #afc2df;
        }
    #box1{

        position fixed;
        border: 120px;
        border-style: groove;
        border-radius:35px;
        width: 505px;
        length: 75px;
        margin-left: 85px;
        z-index: 5;

        }
        this is the table I want to move 

    #table1{

        position fixed;
        background: #00FFFF;
        margin-left: 118px;
        top: 160px;
        z-index: 6;
           }

    </style>
    </head>


    <body>

    <b></b><h1><b><i><font face="impact" color="red">Name</font> </i></b></h1>

    <b></b><h2><b><i><font face="impact" color="red">Number</font> </i></b></h2>

    <table border="3" id="table1">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th colspan="2">WEB PAGE ELEMENTS</th>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Html</th>
                <td><font face="Candara" color="black">Marks beginning and ending of a web page (closing tags needed)</font></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Head</th>
                <td><font face="Candara" color="black">Used to enclose elements not apart of the main page (closing tags needed)</font></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <td><font face="Candara" color="black">Included in the &lt;head&gt; section, appears in the title bar of the browser (closing tags needed)</font></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Body</th>
                <td><font face="Candara" color="black">Includes content that is visible in the browser (closing tag needed)</font></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Meta</th>
                <td><font face="Candara" color="black">Allows passage of information about the page to user agents(self-closing tag)</font></td>

            </tr>
        </tbody></table>





    <div id="box1"></div>






</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS along with my html.

I really want to get good at this and the assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Got any HTML to go with this? :)

Comment: Could you share your html?

Comment: @lefoy  I added my html

Comment: Which software are you using? Your html is a mess... Explain exactly what you're trying to achieve and I'll do my best to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some modifications to clean up your code. **Forewarning:** you will need to dumb this down, do not directly give this *assignment* to your instructor as-is unless they are clueless about anything but the visual output (and if they are leave that college immediately and become self-taught!). Do not rely heavily on the CSS level 2 `position` property, if they haven't taught you about the CSS level 1 `float` then you're going to suffer a potentially permanent inability to code CSS competently.

If you want to learn how to use CSS correctly start with the basics...

http://www.jabcreations.com/web/css/nested-divisible-elements

That being said, this does what you wanted, the page content scrolls while the gigantic bordered division element doesn't.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Assignment 1</title>
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
body
{
 background: #afc2df;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#body
{
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 overflow: auto;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
}
#body > *
{
 margin: 10px;
}
#box1
{
 border: 250px;
 border-style: groove;
 border-radius:35px;
 margin-left: 85px;
 position fixed;
 top: 20px;
 width: 70%;
 z-index: 5;
}
/*this is the table I want to move */

table
{
 height: 900px;
 background: #0ff;
 margin-left: 118px;
}
.candara
{
 font-color: #000;
 font-family: Candara;
}
/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="body">
<h1 style="font-weight: bold; font-family: impact;">Name</h1>

<h2 style="font-weight: bold; font-family: impact;">Number</h2>

<table summary="This summary text is read by screen readers, always provide a summary attribute on table elements.">
<thead><tr><th colspan="2">WEB PAGE ELEMENTS</th></tr></thead>
<tfoot><tr><th colspan="2">WEB PAGE ELEMENTS</th></tr></tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr><th>Html</th><td class="candara">Marks beginning and ending of a web page (closing tags needed)</td></tr>
<tr><th>Head</th><td class="candara">Used to enclose elements not apart of the main page (closing tags needed)</td></tr>
<tr><th>Title</th><td class="candara">Included in the &lt;head&gt; section, appears in the title bar of the browser (closing tags needed)</td></tr>
<tr><th>Body</th><td class="candara">Includes content that is visible in the browser (closing tag needed)</td></tr>
<tr><th>Meta</th><td class="candara">Allows passage of information about the page to user agents(self-closing tag)</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>

<div id="box1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```